# Split dataset in R so that all columns with same name are split into two equal parts?

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like something like this:

```
   A A B C C C D D
X1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 2
X2 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 2
X3 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 2
```

I want to split it into two roughly equal parts in a way that the each column name (e.g. A) would be split equally as well. For example, A and A columns would go into different dataframes (same for D, because it can be split equally), the one B column would go to a random dataframe, and for C, C and C, 2 Cs would go into one, and one C into antoher dataframe. This would be an acceptable result:

```
   A B C C D
X1 1 1 1 2 1
X2 1 1 1 2 1
X3 1 1 1 2 1

   A C D
X1 2 3 2
X2 2 3 2
X3 2 3 2
```

I hope it makes sense. What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about every-other?

```
# if the data.frame is already sorted by column name, skip the next 3 lines
nm <- names(df)
idx <- order(nm)
df <- df[,order(names(df))]
idx <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), ceil(length(df)/2))[1:length(df)]
(df1 <- setNames(df[,idx], names(df)[idx]))
#>    A B C D
#> X1 1 1 2 1
#> X2 1 1 2 1
#> X3 1 1 2 1
(df2 <- setNames(df[,!idx], names(df)[!idx]))
#>    A C C D
#> X1 2 1 3 2
#> X2 2 1 3 2
#> X3 2 1 3 2
```

Comment: Great idea but for some reason I am getting an error "undefined columns selected". Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: The last value in the logical "idx" was set to NA which is why I got the error. I had 9573 columns so I set idx<-c(rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),floor(9573/2)),TRUE) so that the last value would be TRUE instead of NA. Then everything worked.

Comment: @Milda Of course. That was a silly error on my part. `idx <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), ceil(length(df)/2))[1:length(df)]` will work with even or odd numbers of columns.